# How to fix minecraft forge issue in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I'm experiencing an issue with minecraft forge. Whenever I run a project in Eclipse it crashes. Though, I don't experience this issue in IntelliJ. I need Eclipse to complete this as Eclipse has some features that IntelliJ doesn't let me do.

Here's the issue
Unable to initialize main class net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mojang/authlib/exceptions/AuthenticationException

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a library with class named `com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationException` to your project's classpath.

Comment: I'm a little new at this, mind walking me through that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you imported the project into eclipse incorrectly so the system that it's not using the dependency manager they IntelliJ may have automatically sensed and utilized.

For example, if there is a pom.xml in the project directory then you would want to use "import as existing maven project" so that it loads all the right dependencies (packages) needed to run the project.

Comment: pretty sure it's using gradle

Comment: it is using gradle

Comment: Same idea. Different dependency framework. I'm not a gradle user but assuming sclipse has a file->import existing gradle project then be sure you used that to add your project to your workspace and then I would expect eclipse would synch with gradle and jmport all necessary libraries to make your project run as it does in the other IDE.

Comment: All that does is to basically plug in (satisfy) the missing class path entry that msangel noted in the earlier answer.